# How can I start GNU Screen with a specific escape character

Tags: gnu-screen

I know I can change the escape character with

```
escape ^Tt
```

, but how can I start screen with T as escape character.

I've found some references to

```
screen -e ^Tt
```

, but that does not work.

Any pointers?

Comment: it works for me if there's no `escape` command in `screenrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `escape ^Tt` into `.screenrc`.

To start `screen` with a custom RC file you can use `screen -c screenrc.escape_t`.

Comment: Right, I know about these options, but I want to directly specify on the command line, cause it's a dynamic thing, so I don't want to create a whole config file for this.